# Is there a Dev Mode Plugin for the new Firefox 13?

Tags: gwt

To preclude questions about the availability of the GWT Dev Mode plugin for Firefox 13 I'm posting this question and the answer to it below.

So, is there a Dev Mode plugin for the new Firefox 13?

Comment: Why the downvotes for this question? [It's actually encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) to ask and answer your own question if you feel that the bit of knowledge you want to share would be beneficial to others. And as Boris stated, sooner or later there'd be a question about the GWT plugin for FF13 - why not post it earlier and let Google index it and help people find the answer sooner?

Comment: Thanks @IgorKlimer :), I was wondering myself as I watched this 0-sum game of upvotes and downvotes raging on. I posted this because my similar response to a question about Dev Mode plugin for FF12 was well received and I decided to post the info on FF13 preemptively.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is, [thanks again to Alan Leung of Google](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-web-toolkit/EoTbKTvJRyk). Here are the direct FF13 Dev Mode plugin download links from Alan's post: [Linux32](http://acleung.com/ff13-linux32.xpi), [Linux64](http://acleung.com/ff13-linux64.xpi), [Windows](http://acleung.com/ff13-win.xpi), and [Mac](http://acleung.com/ff13-mac.xpi).

Update: the plugin is also available as an [all-platform build](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/plugins/xpcom/prebuilt/gwt-dev-plugin.xpi) in the source repository.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer, even better. Updated the answer to include the link.

Answer (score 1):

Direct link

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/EoTbKTvJRyk

The plugin is also available as an all-platform build.